# Magento 2: How to check if file is selected for upload or not without $_FILES

Tags: magento2, file-upload

I want to check if user has selected file from form or not before saving data. I know that i can use `isset($_FILES['field_name'])` but i don't want to use this is their any other way to check this?

Is magento has any function to check this? If yes then please tell me how to implement it in magento 2.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the \Magento\Framework\File\Uploader class.

Inject the UploaderFactory into your class:

```
public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\File\UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory) {
   $this->_uploaderFactory = $uploaderFactory;
}
```

You can then create an instance and pass the fileId to the constructor:

```
try {
    $uploader = $this->_fileUploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => 'field_name']);

    $uploader->save(/* Specify Path to save file in */);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    //Logic for when $_FILES['field_name'] is not set or file fails to save
}
```

The class will throw an exception if $_FILES is empty or the fileId specified is not set

Comment: I am already using this. but i am having multiple no of file type input on form which are generated dynamically so for that i am using foreach($_FILES['test']){} what will be the alternative for this ?